# Como fazer com que wsmaximized não esconda menu superior?

Tags: delphi

Tenho um form em dephi mas quando eu maximizo ele ou então marco o WindowState = WsMaximized a barra superior some não sendo possível ver os botões de ação (fechar, minimizar) e o título do form.

Alguém sabe de alguma alternativa para que o menu não suma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse não é o comportamento padrão de formulários, você deve ter alterado o valor de alguma propriedade para que isso esteja ocorrendo. Verifique se a propriedade `Align` do *form* está com o valor `AlClient` definido, se estiver altere para `AlNone`.

Verifique também o valor das propriedades `Height` e `Width` do *form* e veja se não há valores absurdos definidos.

Comment: Fiz o que disse mas continua da mesma coisa. Uma coisa que esqueci de dizer é que o form é um fsMDIChild

Comment: Resolvido amigo, era isso mesmo. Obrigado.